# Handling a Undefined offset error when results are 9

Tags: php, wordpress, notice

How would I handle and `Undefined offset 0` error in the situation below? From what I have read the error means no results are being found

**Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in**

```
function style_tag($input) {
    preg_match_all("!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s+href='(.*)' type='text/css' media='(.*)' />!", $input, $matches);

//ERROR HERE
    $staging = $matches[3][0] === 'print' ? ' media="print"' : '';
    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $matches[2][0] . '"' . $staging . '>' . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `preg_match_all` will fail whenever there is no `media` or `href` attribute on the link. You can work around that by wrapping those elements in an optional, non-capturing group:

```
!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s*(?:href='(.*)')?\s*type='text/css'\s*(?:media='(.*)')?\s*/>!
```

so that if not present, they don't cause the match to fail. Complete code:

```
function style_tag($input) {
    preg_match_all("!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s*(?:href='(.*)')?\s*type='text/css'\s*(?:media='(.*)')?\s*/>!", $input, $matches);

    $staging = $matches[3][0] === 'print' ? ' media="print"' : '';
    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $matches[2][0] . '"' . $staging . '>' . "\n";
}

echo style_tag("<link rel='stylesheet' id='someid' href='http://example.com' type='text/css' media='print'/>");
echo style_tag("<link rel='stylesheet' id='someid' href='http://example.com' type='text/css' />");
echo style_tag("<link rel='stylesheet' id='someid' type='text/css' media='print'/>");
```

Output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" media="print">
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HUa3Z)

Comment: I am still getting the Notice 0 error on the same code lines even after the update

Comment: @acctman can you share some sample data which shows the problem?

Comment: I don't want more code, I want a value of `$input` which causes the error to occur...